# Breakdown Between Blob Streamer and Node.js Websocket Server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, https

I have this script running locally (just the file path in the browser):

```
<video id="video-element" autoplay playsinline muted></video>
<canvas></canvas>

<script>

    const videoElement = document.getElementById('video-element')

    async function startVideo() {
        try {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
            videoElement.srcObject = stream;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error accessing camera:', error);
        }
    }

    startVideo();

    const canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
    const canvasContext = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

    socket.onopen = () => {
        console.log('WebSocket connection opened');
    };

    videoElement.addEventListener('play', () => {
        setInterval(() => {
            canvasElement.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
            canvasElement.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
            canvasContext.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, videoElement.videoWidth, videoElement.videoHeight);

            // Convert the frame data to a Blob with the specified MIME type
            canvasElement.toBlob((blob) => {
                if (blob) {
                    // Send the Blob containing the frame data
                    socket.send(blob);
                }
            }, 'image/jpeg', 0.7);

        }, 1000 / 30); // Capture and send frames at approximately 30 frames per second
    });

</script>
```

And then I have this super simple Node.js websocket server running on localhost:8080:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const server = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

server.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log('Client connected');

    ws.on('message', (data) => {

        if (Buffer.isBuffer(data)) {
            // Inspect the first few bytes of the data to determine the content type
            const firstBytes = data.slice(0, 2).toString('hex'); // Get the first 2 bytes as hexadecimal
            
            console.log(firstBytes)
            if (firstBytes === 'ffd8') {
                // Content type is JPEG
                console.log('Received JPEG data');
                // Process the JPEG data here
            } else {
                // Unknown content type
                console.log('Received data with unknown content type');
            }
        }

        // Broadcast the data to other clients
        server.clients.forEach((client) => {
            if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                client.send(data);
            }
        });
    });

    ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
    });
});
```

It's not difficult to get it to run with http when accessing the websocket with another computer on the same network. However, making the jump to https is difficult such as when utilizing a setup like this:

```
import { createServer } from 'https';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';

const server = createServer({
  cert: readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem'),
  key: readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem')
});
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ server });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('error', console.error);

  ws.on('message', function message(data) {
    console.log('received: %s', data);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Here's a diagram of the setup I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Basically, the websocket server is trying to acquire data from index.html and send it to a website running remotely on an website utilizing https with ssl certification from a legitimate CA. For the Node.js server running on my local machine, I've tried self-signed certificates, and I've set up port forwarding for 443.

Here's the code for the webpage attempting to access the WebSocket server currently running remotely. Note the websocket api code at the top of the script element with a placeholder IPV6 wss address:

```
<video id="localVideo" autoplay playsinline muted></video>
<img id="image-element">

<script>

    const socket = new WebSocket('wss://IPV6:8080');

    socket.onopen = (event) => {
        console.log('WebSocket connection opened:', event);
    };

    function convertBlobToImage(blob) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (event) {
            // When the Blob data is loaded, create an image element
            const imageElement = document.getElementById('image-element');
            const data = event.target.result;

            imageElement.src = data;

            console.log(data)
        };

    // Read the Blob data, triggering the `onload` function when done
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}

    socket.onmessage = (event) => {

        const imageElement = document.getElementById('image-element');

        const blobData = event.data;

        console.log(typeof blobData)

        // Convert blobData to an image

        convertBlobToImage(blobData);

    };

    socket.onerror = (error) => {
        console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
    };

    socket.onclose = (event) => {
    if (event.wasClean) {
        console.log('WebSocket connection closed cleanly:', event.reason);
      } else {
        console.error('WebSocket connection abruptly closed:', event.reason);
      }
    };    


</script>
```

However, it seems like the breakdown is occurring between index.html and the websocket server, and blob data is not making it to the websocket server. My question is how do I get wss to work properly between all the different parts of this project?